# Передача параметра функции php

Tags: php

Есть метод в файле api.php, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
    public function cnb_form($params)
{

$language = 'ru';
if (isset($params['language']) && $params['language'] == 'en') {
$language = 'en';
}

$params = $this->cnb_params($params);
$data = base64_encode( json_encode($params) );
$signature = $this->cnb_signature($params);

return sprintf('
<form method="POST" action="%s" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="price">
%s
%s
<input type="submit">
</form>
',
$this->_checkout_url,
sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />', 'data', $data),
sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s" />', 'signature', $signature),
$language
);
$price = $_POST['price'];
}
```

Мне нужно передать значение суммы (price) в другую функцию (находится в файле my.php)

```
 function addbalance($price){
require("api.php");

$micro = sprintf("%06d",(microtime(true) - floor(microtime(true))) * 1000000);
$number = date("YmdHis");
$order_id = $number.$micro;

$merchant_id= "****";
$signature="****";

//$desc = $_GET[‘desc’];
//$order_id = $_GET[‘order_id’];
$liqpay = new LiqPay($merchant_id, $signature);
$html = $liqpay->cnb_form(array(
'version' => '3',
'amount' => $price,
'currency' => 'UAH',
'description' => "Пополнение баланса",
'order_id' => $order_id
));

echo $html;
}
```

Параметр введённого баланса пользователем не передаётся в функцию.  В ООП новичок. И после длительных раздумий совсем запутался. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: но какой смысл? $_POST['price'] глобальная она доступна везде. в функции addbalance() вместо использования $price использовать $_POST['price']??? во вторых $price = $_POST['price']; эта строка находится после оператора return и переменная не будет обьявлена никогда

Answer (score 0):

Штука в том, что весь этот веб работает немного иначе. Взаимодействие пользователя с вашей программой происходит
через обмен HTTP запросами и ответами. То есть, сперва пользователь запросит (GET-запрос) у вашего приложения HTML-форму для ввода данных,
которую вы собираете в функции `cnb_form`. Если у вас хоть что-то работает, то где-то далее по коду вы отправляете ответ пользоватлею
(в PHP это происходит не совсем явно, но если вы делаете echo или print, то строка попадает в тело ответа). Затем пользователь заполнит форму
и отправит новый запрос в ваше приложение (на этот раз POST-запрос) и только тогда у вас будет `$_POST['price']`.

Обратите внимание, что в PHP (как и во многих других языках) `return` из функции прервёт выполнение функции, а всё, что расположено ниже просто не выполнится.
Последняя строчка в `cnb_form` никогда не отрабатывает. Кроме того, сам код `$price = $_POST['price'];` не имеет смысла в контексте GET-запроса.

Теперь ответ на ваш вопрос. `$price` является аргументом функции `addbalance` и передавать его надо при вызове функции. В самом простом
случае вам надо отыскать вызов и передать туда значение из глобальнго массива `$_POST`: `addbalance($_POST['price'])`. Однако, скорее всего, это
не решит вашей проблемы, потому что она, видимо, заключается в незнании PHP.

Подозреваю, что вы накопировали кода из документации LiqPay или позаимствовали у других разработчиков и пытаетесь это как-то завести.
Отступитесь. Прежде всего разберитесь с тем
как работает сайт, изучите основы PHP. И когда начнёт возникать понимание того, что происходит в коде, который вы демонстрируете, вы сможете справится с задачей
подключения платёжной системы. А пока либо доверьте это дело более опытным разработчикам, либо отложите задачу до тех пор, пока не наберётесь опыта.